# How can I dynamically write a reducer (useReducer hook)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a dynamic reducer to loop over a list and setting each item in this list a counter. 
I am not sure I am doing it right - mainly in the section where I set it a value of ' ' (and can't dynamically name it or set the value I want initially (each will have a different value))

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'SET_COUNTER':
        return {
          ...state,
          [`counter${action.id}`]: action.payload
        }
        default:
          return state
    }
  }

//is the below correct?
  let [{ counter }, dispatchReducer] = useReducer(reducer, {
    counter: '',
  })
```

I am then looping over an array of objects to create different counters (e.g. `counter0, counter1, counter2 ...`) and set each of them a value

```
//this dispatch is not working
useEffect(() => {
    availableTimes.map(item => 
      dispatchReducer({
        type: 'SET_COUNTER',
        id: item.id,
        payload: counts[`${item.time}`]
      })
    )
  }, [])
```

The payload comes from an object which I am using to count the instances of a time. E.g. if "2230" appears 3 times, this object will have `"2230": 3`

```
const counts = {}

extractedTiesm.forEach(x => {
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1
  })

//console.log(counts["2230"])  --> 3
```

Comment: What's the initial value of reducer?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I don't really understand your question. I edited the post to see if that might answer it

Comment: Are you sure you need a reducer for that ? simply reduce the list to get the data + its count

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI I think I might do... I explain in further detail in this url (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255139/how-to-dynamically-use-usereducer-when-looping-over-a-list). I will later need to set that counter again later, for each item in the list